# Flask app does not use routes defined in another module

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, flask

I can't get it to work to use one module that creates the Flask application object and runs it, and one module that implements the views (routes and errorhandlers). The modules are *not* contained in a Python package.

**`app.py`**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('graphlog')

import config
import views

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=config.host, port=config.port, debug=config.debug)
```

**`views.py`**

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello!'
```

**`config.py`**

```
host = 'localhost'
port = 8080
debug = True
```

I always get Flask's default "404 Not Found" page. If I move the contents of `view.py` to `app.py` however, it works. What's the problem here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It prints the module object I expect, the `views.py` from the same directory as `app.py`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes! (Well, it prints the Flask app, also right). Btw, I just tried moving it to a Python Package instead (`graphlog/app.py`, `graphlog/views.py`, `graphlog/config.py` and `graphlog/__init__.py`) and it works with `python -m graphlog.app`. Maybe a bug in Flask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have **four** modules here:

- `__main__`, the main script, the file you gave to the Python command to run.
- `config`, loaded from the `config.py` file.
- `views`, loaded from the `views.py` file.
- `app`, loaded from `app.py` when you use `import app`.

Note that the latter is **separate** from the first! The initial script is not loaded as `app` and Python sees it as different. You have two `Flask` objects, one referenced as `__main__.app`, the other as `app.app`.

Create a *separate* file to be the main entry point for your script; say `run.py`:

```
from app import app
import config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=config.host, port=config.port, debug=config.debug)
```

and remove the `import config` line from `app.py`, as well as the last two lines.

Alternatively (but much uglier), use `from __main__ import app` in `views.py`.

Comment: I get `module 'app' has no attribute 'run'`

Comment: @jul: `app` is the name of the `Flask()` instance (the OP has `app = Flask('graphlog')`). Adjust accordingly.

Comment: `app` is the name of the module. Shouldn't it be `from app import app`?

Comment: @jul: ah, yes, I now spotted what you mean; adjusted accordingly.